# How to use array_push in map method in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

```php
$ids = [1];
$collection = collect([2]);
$collection->map(function ($item) use ($ids) {
   array_push($ids, $item);
});
dd($ids);
```

This code returns

> array:1 [
> 0 => 1
> ]

I thought this would return `[1, 2]` because of `array_push`;

How can I get `[1, 2]` or
`array:2 [ 0 => 1  1 => 2 ]` ?

Comment: Whats the structure of `$item` and how many items are there in `$collection`?

Comment: Also try initializing the `$ids` as `$ids = array()`

Comment: @Chin. Udara `$item` is int 2. `$collection` has one item.

Comment: it need to push from map to outsite array collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ids = [1];
$item_collection = $collection->map(function ($item) {
   return $item;
})
->all();

$result = array_push($ids, $item_collection);
```

This probably would work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you require a map function to do this.

```
        $ids = [1];
        $collection = collect($ids);
        
        $item = [2];
        $collection = $collection->conact($item);
        
        dd($collection);
 

   /*
    Illuminate\Support\Collection {#4937
      #items: array:2 [
        0 => 1
        1 => 2
      ]
    }
*/
```

Or use merge:

```
$collection = collect([1]);
$collection = $collection->merge([2]);

dd($collection);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ids = collect([1]);
$collection = collect([2,3,4]);
$collection->map(function ($item,$i) use ($ids) {
   $ids->push($item);
});
dd($ids);
```

This is will push data from collection mapping to outside array declared